# Does the time of heating of multicomponent system depend on the order, in which the components are heated?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

Let's say I have a source of heat, an engine, and two systems - cooling tubes and the air inside the car. Let the temperature of the engine be $T_e$, temperature of the other two components $T_s < T_e$. Also assume, that air is only in contact with the tubes, just like the engine. Will the system of the air and the tubes reach temperature $T, \;T_s<T<T_e$ faster, if both systems are put into contact at the same time, or if we first heat up the tubes? Is the heat capacity of the engine an important factor?